# jqGrid drag and drop into a folder

Tags: javascript, jqgrid

I have a jqGrid which contains folders and documents.  I want to be able to drag and drop the documents into the folders within the same grid.  Does jqGrid support that, either directly or via a few different plugins, or do I have to write custom javascript for it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

jqGrid has support for dragging and dropping rows between two grids.

http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:jquery_ui_methods#drag_and_drop_rows_between_grids

You may be able to connect the grid to itself and handle the events (assuming the events fire when a grid is connected to itself)

**connectWith** - Determines the target grid(s) to which the row should be dropped. The option is a string. In case of more than one grid the ids should be delemited with comma - i.e ”#grid1, #grid2”

Comment: thanks for the reply. I'm not sure if I understand what you said... I want to drag and drop say a document to a folder all within the one jqGrid... a bit like what we do in windows explorer. I had a brief look at the jqGrid sites and couldnt find any cheap ways of doing it.

Comment: when you say drag-and-drop a document, do you mean drag it from an external program (like Windows Explorer) into your web browser, or are these documents really just rows on the grid that represent documents? If it's the latter, you may be better off using some sort of treeview plugin like http://www.jstree.com/